# An increasing sequence of positive sets in Hahn's decomposition theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

> **The Hahn Decomposition Theorem.** If $\nu$ is a signed measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$, there exist a positive set $P$ and a negative set $N$ for $\nu$ such that $P\cup N=X$ and $P\cap N=\emptyset.$

Let $$m=\sup\{\nu(E)\;:\; \text{$E\;$ positive set}\},$$ then exists a sequence $\{Q_k\}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ of positive sets such that $$m=\lim_{k\to\infty}\nu(Q_k).$$ Now, we define $$P_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^n Q_k,$$ then $\{P_n\}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ is an increasing sequence of positive sets.

> Can I conclude that $$m=\lim_{n\to\infty}\nu(P_n)?$$
> It would seem so, but I don't know the reason. Could anyone give me some hints?

**My Solution.**

Since for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $P_n$ is a positive set, results that $\nu(P_n)\le m$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, from which we deduce that $$\lim \nu(P_n)\le m.$$
On the other hand $Q_n\subseteq P_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and then $P_n=Q_n\sqcup (P_n\setminus Q_n)$ and therefore $$\nu(P_n)=\nu(Q_n)+\nu(P_n\setminus Q_n)\ge \nu(Q_n)$$ since $\nu(P_n\setminus Q_n)\ge 0$ being $P_n$ a positive set and $P_n\setminus Q_n\subseteq P_n$.

It's correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine!

Only question: Why is a (countable) union of positive sets positive?

Comment: It's an exercise I've already done, it's very easy to do.